# How can I properly migrate a connected component from class based to functional component on TS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, redux

I am attempting to migrate from a class based component to functional component. It is a connected component using `mapState`.

This is what I had:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchArticles } from '../shared/actions/articleActions';
import { AppState } from '../shared/types/genericTypes';
import Article from '../shared/models/Article.model';

type Props = {
  articles?: Article[]
  fetchArticles?: any,
};

const mapState = (state: AppState, props) => ({
  articles: state.articleReducers.articles,
  ...props
});

const actionCreators = {
  fetchArticles,
};

class NewsArticles extends Component<Props> {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.articles || !this.props.articles.length) {
      this.props.fetchArticles();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (...);
  }
}

export default connect(mapState, actionCreators)(NewsArticles)
```

Here is what I have now:

```
// same imports except for FC and useEffec from react.

type Props = {
  articles?: Article[];
  fetchArticles?: any;
};

const mapState = (state: AppState, props: Props) => ({
  articles: state.articleReducers.articles,
  ...props,
});

const actionCreators = {
  fetchArticles,
};

const NewsArticles: FC<Props> = ({ articles, fetchArticles }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!articles || !articles.length) {
      fetchArticles();
    }
  }, []);

  return (...);
};

export default connect(mapState, actionCreators)(NewsArticles);
```

The main concern I have is the props.

Before they were like this

```
const mapState = (state: AppState, props) => ({
  articles: state.articleReducers.articles,
  ...props
});
```

And used like this:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.articles || !this.props.articles.length) {
      this.props.fetchArticles();
    }
  }
```

Now that I have a functional component, I am getting this

```
const mapState = (state: AppState, props: Props) => ({
  articles: state.articleReducers.articles,
  ...props,
});
```

And used like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!articles || !articles.length) {
      fetchArticles();
    }
  }, []);
```

So how `props` will work now that `articles` and `fetchArticles` are not called like `this.props.articles` and only `articles` so, does make any sense to spread props `…props` on `mapState`?

Comment: yes, what you have done is absolutely correct, what comes in props is not dependent on whether the Component is Class or functional. its is provided by the connect HOC

Comment: The props in your mapState call are of course the component's own props, so if you want to assign any other props it might receive to its state then spreading them in the map call makes sense.  But unless you're performing some kind of operation on the props, and often even if you are, deriving state from them is usually unnecessary.  So regardless of the component type it's not required, but there's no real downside to it.

Comment: No need to spread `props`. All props that `NewsArticles ` need are provided by `connect`: `articles ` from `state` and `fetchArticles ` from `actionCreators `

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to spread props in `mapState`.

This:

```
const mapState = (state: AppState, props: Props) => ({
  articles: state.articleReducers.articles,
  ...props,
});
```

is equivalent to this:

```
const mapState = (state: AppState) => ({
  articles: state.articleReducers.articles,
});
```

Any extra props will get passed into your component in addition to the props from `mapState` and `mapDispatch` (which you've called `actionCreators`).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is compilable but is not fully correct with `connect` function signature. Lets look on signature

```
<TStateProps = {}, TDispatchProps = {}, TOwnProps = {}, State = {}>(
    mapStateToProps: MapStateToPropsParam<TStateProps, TOwnProps, State>,
    mapDispatchToProps: MapDispatchToPropsNonObject<TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>
): InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<TStateProps & TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>;
```

It has 4 types,

1. `TSTateProps` is type of props, derived from Redux state. In your sample they are

   ```
   type StateProps = {
       articles: Article[];
   }
   ```

   Only `articles` are derived from Redux state.
2. `TDispatchProps` is type of props containing actions your component will dispatch. As you passing `actionCreators` object to `connect` `TDispatchProps` should equal to `typeof actionCreators` (we should get type of object `actionCreators`).
3. `TOwnProps` is type of props your component get from parent (not from Redux). You not use props from parent, so `TOwnProps` will equal to `{}`.
4. `TState` is type of state in Redux. It is `AppState`.

So to be fully correct with Redux, you should do

```
type StateProps = {
    articles: Article[];
};

const mapState = (state: AppState): StateProps => ({
    articles: state.articleReducers.articles
});

const actionCreators = {
    fetchArticles,
};

type Props = StateProps & typeof actionCreators;  // These is correct props for your component

const NewsArticles: FC<Props> = ({ articles, fetchArticles }) => {
```

And in case you'll later add props from parent, just intersect them with `Props`.

```
type Props = StateProps & typeof actionCreators & OwnProps;
```

Your code worked as you added `...props` to `mapState`. And `props` contained member `fetchAction`. So you finally got the same `Props` like I showed in my answer, but slightly incorrect.